# Storing HTML in database codeigniter

Tags: php, html, database, codeigniter, content-management-system

I am creating a CMS with codeigniter and need to store some text that is wrapped in html. I will then get the data from the database and echo it onto my page. What is the best way to do this being security conscious?

Example of data:

```
<h2>A fresh approach</h2>
    <p>Whether you have queries regarding your</p>
<a href="#">cgoto page</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sanitization** is always necessary.

I'm a particular fan of using white lists for HTML tags so you analyze the data you're about to store and simply wipe out the HTML tags that are not in that white list. This way, if you desire, you can prevent users from inserting certain tags like `<script>` or `<object>` with unpredictable or obscure behavior.

> Suppose one of your CMS users uses a very dumb password and someone
>   else gains access over the application. Filtering HTML content would
>   prevent the impostor from inserting malicious cross domain javascript
>   to collect keyboard events (that might reveal possible passwords in
>   login forms) and etc.

Also it's always good to validate the HTML you're going to store since any invalid HTML would end up hurting your website markup and even breaking your rendering in some browsers.

Doing that checks before storing things in database might not be enough since data can be corrupted by direct database access, so before echoing the content do what @RodrigoFerreira said.

Comment: True. But if the attacker already has direct access to the database, filtering content on output will be the smallest problem to solve... ;) I usually apply htmlentities filter on output (so I can except raw HTML data under certain conditions, as he should in this case) and xss filter before saving to the database (the best approach for performance, instead of filtering the same data again and again each request).

Comment: The filter before and after approach is still the most secure, he just needs to find a performance balance that suits his needs :] I was **not talking about direct database hacking**, was referring to database inconsistencies caused by any direct database manipulation (including crazy DBAs running crazy maintenance scripts, yes it happens lol).

Answer (score 3):

Apply a XSS filter before saving (better, because you'll save once and echo several times) or on output and assign the content to a variable passed to the view. You may use $this->security->xss_clean($data_retrieved).